# HTML5 - Chrome 44 - text in flexbox not aligning properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Having trouble getting my code to look right on Chrome (works fine on Firefox 39 and IE 8). Text inside the flexbox I created is aligned weirdly in Chrome. It justifies the first line to the left, the second line to the center, and a third line to the right (instead of placing them on top of each other as they should be).

```css
header {background-color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Georgia; font-size: 3em; border: 1px solid white; margin: 0px; padding: 5px;}
nav {background-color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Veranda, sans-serif; border: 1px solid white; margin: 0px; padding: 8px; 0.9em; border-bottom:2px solid #000000;}
section {font-family: Veranda, sans-serif; margin: 0px; padding: 20px; font-size: 08.em;}
footer {background-color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Veranda, sans-serif; font-size: 0.7em; border: 1px solid white; margin: 0px; padding: 8px; border-top: 2px solid #000000;}

.main{background-image: url(BG-IMAGE GOES HERE); height: 255px; border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;}
.second{background-image: url();}

.smaller{font-size:65%;}

#flexbox{ 

display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-webkit-box-align: center;

display: -webkit-inline-flex;
-webkit-inline-flex-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-inline-flex-pack: center;
-webkit-inline-flex-align: center;

display: -moz-box;
-moz-box-orient: horizontal;
-moz-box-pack: center;
-moz-box-align: center;

display: -ms-flexbox;
-ms-flexbox-orient: horizontal;
-ms-flexbox-pack: center;
-ms-flexbox-align: center;

display: box;
box-orient: horizontal;
box-pack: center;
box-align: center;

background-color: #FFFFFF;
border: 2px solid #000000;
padding: 20px;
font-family: Tahoma;
width: 50%;
font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<header>

<center>
<img height="125px" width="125px" src="logo1.png"><br>
TITLE
</center>

</header>

<nav>
<center>
<a class="one" href="LINK">HOME</a> | <a class="one" href="LINK">LINK</a> | <a class="one" href="LINK">LINK</a> | <a class="one" href="LINK">LINK</a> | <a class="one" href="CONTACT US">CONTACT US</a>
</center>
</nav>

<section class="main">

<center>
<br>

<div id="flexbox">

<br><i>&quot;TEXT GOES HERE AND HERE AND HERE AS WELL&quot;</i><br><br>
<p align="right"><span class="smaller">- Some Guy, <i>From This Thing</i></span></p>
<br>
MORE TEXT
</div>
<br><br>
</center>

</section>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you select the text, it's clear that the boxes are getting aligned to the middle:  So you probably just need to adjust the padding margin on the second box and remove the br before the third box:

[image]

```css
body{vertical-align:top;!important}
header {background-color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Georgia; font-size: 3em; border: 1px solid white; margin: 0px; padding: 5px;}
nav {background-color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Veranda, sans-serif; border: 1px solid white; margin: 0px; padding: 8px; 0.9em; border-bottom:2px solid #000000;}
section {font-family: Veranda, sans-serif; margin: 0px; padding: 20px; font-size: 08.em;}
footer {background-color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Veranda, sans-serif; font-size: 0.7em; border: 1px solid white; margin: 0px; padding: 8px; border-top: 2px solid #000000;}

.main{background-image: url(BG-IMAGE GOES HERE); height: 255px; border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;}
.second{background-image: url();}

.smaller{font-size:65%;}

#flexbox{ 

display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-pack: center;
-webkit-box-align: center;

display: -webkit-inline-flex;
-webkit-inline-flex-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-inline-flex-pack: center;
-webkit-inline-flex-align: center;

display: -moz-box;
-moz-box-orient: horizontal;
-moz-box-pack: center;
-moz-box-align: center;

display: -ms-flexbox;
-ms-flexbox-orient: horizontal;
-ms-flexbox-pack: center;
-ms-flexbox-align: center;

display: box;
box-orient: horizontal;
box-pack: center;
box-align: center;

background-color: #FFFFFF;
border: 2px solid #000000;
padding: 20px;
font-family: Tahoma;
width: 50%;
font-size: 1.5em;

}
```

```html
<header>

<center>
<img height="125px" width="125px" src="logo1.png"><br>
TITLE
</center>

</header>

<nav>
<center>
<a class="one" href="LINK">HOME</a> | <a class="one" href="LINK">LINK</a> | <a class="one" href="LINK">LINK</a> | <a class="one" href="LINK">LINK</a> | <a class="one" href="CONTACT US">CONTACT US</a>
</center>
</nav>

<section class="main">

<center>
<br>

<div id="flexbox">

<br><i>&quot;TEXT GOES HERE AND HERE AND HERE AS WELL&quot;</i><br><br>
<p align="right" style="-webkit-margin-before:0px"><span class="smaller">- Some Guy, <i>From This Thing</i></span><br><br></p>

MORE TEXT
</div>
<br><br>
</center>

</section>
```